# JQuery load (on an svg) into HTML div isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <!-- initial rendition -->
            <html>
                <head>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        $(function () { 
                            $('#bat').load('sample.svg');
                        });

                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="bat">
                        <!--
                        <svg height="100" width="100">
                            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
                        </svg> 
                        -->
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

I wrote this short code to test it and it's still not working. The contents of "sample.svg" is the commented out svg tag in #bat. When uncommented the svg in #bat displays just fine.

"sample.svg" is in the same directory as this html.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try loading it into an img tag as the src

Comment: try using `/sample.svg` instead.. or if its not in your home directory do `/thisdirectory/sample.svg` and see if that makes any difference